# Change position of title in amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I created a simple graph with [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com) and set a title.
Is it possible to change its position? In my case I want the title to be on the left of the graph, maybe even in an angle of 90 degree:

[image]

This is an extract of the code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  //..
  , "titles": [{
    "text": "My Chart Title"
  }, {
    "text": "My Chart Sub-Title",
    "bold": false
  }]
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/me05n6m3/).

Comment: Override the css of the plugin.

Comment: access with .amcharts-title { }

Comment: @CarolMcKay:I already tried with `.amcharts-title {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  }`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: It would have been good if you included this information (what you have tried) in your question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use [label functionality](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label) instead?

Contrary to `titles`, labels can be any text placed anywhere in the chart area, rotated, etc.

```
"allLabels": [{
  "text": "My Chart Title",
  "bold": true,
  "x": 10,
  "y": "50%",
  "rotation": 270,
  "width": "100%",
  "align": "middle"
}, {
  "text": "My Chart Sub-Title",
  "bold": false,
  "x": 30,
  "y": "50%",
  "rotation": 270,
  "width": "100%",
  "align": "middle"
}]
```

The only downside is that you will need to manually adjust chart's margins to accommodate for them. The chart does not auto-adjust margins as with titles.

Since you want the labels on the left side, the same as value axis, setting `marginLeft` will be ignored because the axis will try to auto-calculate the margin needed for the axis' labels. (not counting in the labels)

To fix that set [`ignoreAxisWidth`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#ignoreAxisWidth) on the value axis to `true`.

[Here's your Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/me05n6m3/2/).

Comment: Please see my update. I want the title to be at the side of the chart.

Comment: Updated my answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

As said **@Lara_Belle** you can modify this with **css** hack.

You can add **css** transform for move your text. I used `nth-child` for assign **css** on subtitle. Please try below.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "color": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "color": "#F8FF01"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "color": "#B0DE09"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "color": "#04D215"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "color": "#0D8ECF"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "color": "#0D52D1"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "color": "#2A0CD0"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "color": "#8A0CCF"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "color": "#CD0D74"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors from country"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }, "titles": [{
    "text": "My Chart Title"
  }, {
    "text": "My Chart Sub-Title",
    "bold": false
  }]

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.amcharts-export-menu-top-right {
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}
text{
  margin: 50px;
}

.amcharts-title{
  transform: translate(145px,30px)
}
.amcharts-title:nth-child(2){
  transform: translate(134px, 10px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**UPADATE**

You can just modify the transform property. 
ex:

```
.amcharts-title{
  transform: translate(145px,30px)
}
.amcharts-title:nth-child(2){
  transform: translate(134px, 10px)
}
```

Please try now

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't mean **align left**, but **left from the chart**. Just next to `Visitors from country`.

Comment: You can just modify the transform property. Please try the update

Comment: Please see my update. I want the title to be at the side of the chart.